# windows batch file for mysqldump command

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file

this is first time I am upto making a windows batch file.I wish not to do experiments first as its related to live server.
I use to back up mySql database by following 
open cmd 
write

```
mysqldump -u user -p DBname >C:\DBname.sql
```

then cmd ask password

```
password = password
```

I want to make a windows batch file ,upon click I wish to perform the above functionality.
Can any one please give some instructions related script of .bat file

So far I wrote this

```
ECHO OFF
mysqldump -u user -p DBname >C:\DBname.sql
GO
SET password = password 
Go
```

but still it prompts me for password . 
I wish password get enter automatically

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The one-liner:

`mysqldump -u user -p DBname --password YOURPASSWORD > C:\DBname.sql`

should do it.

Comment: yes ,thanks , i did following
ECHO OFF
mysqldump -u user -ppassword DBname >C:\DBname.sql
GO

Comment: great thank you. I forgot `-p` for password parameter. Because of my password has 'p' for first character. ;)

Comment: Could you maybe write out the whole program in your answer? I'm a beginner with `.bat` and it's hard for me to piece it together from this answer/question above.

Answer (score 14):

The above was still prompting me for a password I used whats below to get it to work correctly.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe" -uroot -pDBPass DBName > C:\DBname.sql
```

Comment: when you do `-ppassword` instead of `-p password` it worked as expected, upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe" -u root -proot test > D:\DBname.sql
```

Please note this: `-proot`, the `p` and `root` must be together

Answer (score 0):

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqldump.exe" -u root -pmypassword --databases mydatabase --hex-blob > C:\mybackup.sql
```

Paste into a bat file, I couldnt get the plain command to work in task scheduler so used a BAT

You can omit the --hex-blob, its there incase you're using blob columns